# Comparison of $A$ and $B$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let $a>b>0$ and $n\in N*$. Comparison of  $$A=\frac{1+a+a^2+...+a^{n-1}}{1+a+a^2+...+a^n}$$ and $$B=\frac{1+b+b^2+...+b^{n-1}}{1+b+b^2+...+b^n}$$

---

We have: $\frac{\left(a-1\right)\left(1+a+a^2+...+a^{n-1}\right)}{\left(a-1\right)}=\frac{a^n-1}{a-1}$

And $\frac{\left(a-1\right)\left(1+a+a^2+...+a^n\right)}{\left(a-1\right)}=\frac{a^{n+1}-1}{a-1}$

So $A=\frac{a^n-1}{a^{n+1}-1}$. Similar for $B=\frac{b^n-1}{b^{n+1}-1}$

But $A-B=-\frac{a^n-b^n+a^{n+1}b^n-a^nb^{n+1}-\left(a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}\right)}{\left(a^{n+1}-1\right)\left(b^{n+1}-1\right)}=-\frac{\left(a-b\right)\cdot \:F\left(a,b\right)+\left(a-b\right)\cdot \:Q\left(a,b\right)-\left(a^{n+1}-b^{n+1}\right)}{\left(a^{n+1}-1\right)\left(b^{n+1}-1\right)}$

Then I can't continue this work. Help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A=1-{a^n\over1+a+\cdots+a^n}=1-{1\over1+a^{-1}+\cdots+a^{-n}}$ is clearly a decreasing function of $a$.

Comment: Tks for your help, I solved it.